# how to exit or stop a running thread in c?

Tags: c, winapi, multithreading

i am using Win32 API.

i have a thread in c and want to terminate it from out side the thread so can't use exitthread()

i can't use any wait options cause i have to kill this thread and start it again in very short time.

need help,

Comment: possible duplicate of [kill thread in pthread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084830/kill-thread-in-pthread)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminating a thread gracefully not using TerminateThread()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702172/terminating-a-thread-gracefully-not-using-terminatethread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can thermiate the thread using TerminateThread using the thread handle you got from CreateThread. 
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717(VS.85).aspx

Please note the warning in the MSDN site. Terminating a thread is dangerous.

Consider that the thread can have resources allocated, that will not released when you terminate it as you describe. Example: if the thread has entered a critical section and is terminated before leaving, you won't be able to enter the CS with another thread.